# My terminal returns ;5A;5D;5B;5C whenever I use CTRL+arrow

Tags: linux, freebsd

I'm using `CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)` and I ssh into following system:

```
$ uname -a
FreeBSD X 9.2-RELEASE-p5 FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p5 #0 r265974: Wed May 14 07:57:04 PDT 2014     root@X:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/R610  amd64
$
```

Whenever I try to use `CTRL` + `arrow` like I do in Linux terminal, I'm getting following:

```
[alexus@j ~]$ ;5A;5D;5B;5C
```

My Linux's `$TERM`:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```

How would one resolve that?

*** UPDATE ***

per `user8558`:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ tail -4 /etc/inputrc 
# for freebsd console
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
$endif
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```

Comment: what is the value of `$TERM` outside the SSH session and what inside? And are you on a Linux virtual console or inside some terminal emulator inside X?

Does it help if you run GNU screen on your Linux machine (outside the SSH connection) or on your FreeBSD machine (inside the SSH connection)?

Comment: @mihi My `Linux` `$TERM` is `xterm-256color` and after ssh in to `FreeBSD`, it's still same (I'm on physical `Linux` workstation). After running `screen`, `$TERM` changes to `screen-256color` with same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

following solved my issue:

```
[root@j ~]# tail -1 /etc/profile 
export INPUTRC=/usr/local/etc/inputrc
[root@j ~]# cat /usr/local/etc/inputrc 
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
[root@j ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in /etc/termcap or /etc/terminfo (not sure which one FreeBSD uses) if there is a termcap entry for `xterm-256color`.

If yes, it is probably wrong (or whatever program you are in is not correctly using the terminal information but trying to parse terminal codes manually; if you have a version of GNU Bash on your FreeBSD, try starting this one and reproducing it inside, as it is known to properly use termcap/terminfo). Perhaps you find some compatibility setting to put into your `.termcap` to resolve this.

If no, either find some example to add (or recompile termcap/terminfo in case a more recent version has it), or change the settings of your terminal emulator (I assume `xterm`) to emulate a different terminal (like `xterm` or `linux` or `rxvt`) instead.

Perhaps this one helps:
https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/howto-escape-from-rxvt-unicode-256color-termcap-terminfo-and-screen-hell.13345/

Answer (score 0):

The `TERM` environment variable probably won't be enough, because we are talking not about the cursor moving maneuvers, but about the command line editing tool. You need to set up in your command line editing library, which command can enable the cursor moving in the different directions.

Your shell is probably bash, which uses the readline library for command line editing. This library can be configured with the configuration files `/etc/inputrc` or with the `.inputrc` in your home.

What you need to set up in them: (example from [here](https://docs.freebsd.org/info/readline/readline.info.Sample_Init_File.html)).

```
 # Arrow keys in 8 bit ANSI mode
 #
 "\M-\C-[D"       backward-char
 "\M-\C-[C"       forward-char
 "\M-\C-[A"       previous-history
 "\M-\C-[B"       next-history
```

The actual sequences (in the first column) may be change on your special case, but this will probably work.

Comment: I assume you're referring for `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc` on my `Linux` as I don't have that in my `FreeBSD`. I found few lines for freebsd (`beginning-of-line` and of `end-of-line`) I tested it and it works. I'll paste it to my question so everyone can see.